# Cast objects passed using @Input() to an Interface type in typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, data-sharing

I want to pass objects from parent component to the child component using @Input() and in the child component I want to cast it to an Interface.
Interface definition

```
    export interface IDummy {
    name: string;
    issueNumber: number;
    }
```

In my parent.component.ts

```
    dummyVariable = {"name":"typescript","issue":"problem with casting objects to an interface using Input"};
```

In my parent.component.html

```
    <child-component [dummyVariable]="dummyVariable"></child-component>
```

In my child.component.ts

```
    @Input() dummyVariable:IDummy;//it should throw an error saying that it is missing an interface property issueNumber, but it runs successfully without throwing an error.
```

What is it that I'm doing wrong?

Comment: why you create interface..?

Comment: I'm building a library which accepts few inputs from an external application to generate a response. The values the library accepts should be in a particular format and I want to enforce that format to users. Like if my library needs an integer value, the library should throw an error if a String value is passed from an external application. And so I'm using Interfaces

Comment: I'll be surprised if prod build will work (cause of aot). Any error when running ```ng build --prod```?

Comment: Did you try adding this to tsconfig: ```"angularCompilerOptions": {
    "fullTemplateTypeCheck": true,
    "strictInjectionParameters": true
  }```

Comment: Also, which version of angular are you running? Ivy has better template checking by far.

Comment: I think it won't throw an error during execution since Interfaces are not a runtime construct. I read somewhere that Interfaces are removed during runtime. I think in my case that is what is happening. But I'm not sure.

Comment: My tsconfig has  "angularCompilerOptions": {"fullTemplateTypeCheck": true}, "strictInjectionParameters": true } and I'm using Angular 9